# Jenkins sudo: a terminal is required to read the password

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, code-coverage

I have a FastAPI app for which I have configured Jenkins pipeline. When I execute unit tests with the code coverage enabled they are failing with the following error :

```
Started by user gold
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/edtshuma/devsecops-labs.git
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Python-DevSecOps
....
....
[Pipeline] sh
+ pip install -r requirements.txt
....
Requirement already satisfied: uvicorn==0.20.0 in ./.pyenv-usr-bin-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 41)) (0.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: watchfiles==0.18.1 in ./.pyenv-usr-bin-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 42)) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets==10.4 in ./.pyenv-usr-bin-python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 43)) (10.4)
+ sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins ./docs/unit-tests/htmlcoverage
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withPythonEnv
```

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
 agent any
  
triggers {
    githubPush()
}
stages {
    
    stage('Setup'){
       steps{
       withPythonEnv('/usr/bin/python3.8') {
            sh 'echo "Job is starting" '
        }            
        }
     }    
stage('Unit Tests'){ 
           steps{
               withPythonEnv('/usr/bin/python3.8') {
                 sh '''pip install -r requirements.txt
                       sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins ./docs/unit-tests/htmlcoverage
                       pytest -v --junitxml=docs/unit-tests/htmlcoverage/coverage.xml --cov-report xml --cov app.main
                '''
             }           
            }                    
         }                
       stage('Publish Test Report'){ 
           steps{
              cobertura autoUpdateHealth: false, autoUpdateStability: false, coberturaReportFile: 'coverage*.xml', conditionalCoverageTargets: '70, 0, 0', failUnhealthy: false, failUnstable: false, lineCoverageTargets: '80, 0, 0', maxNumberOfBuilds: 0, methodCoverageTargets: '80, 0, 0', onlyStable: false, sourceEncoding: 'ASCII', zoomCoverageChart: false
              archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'docs/unit-tests/htmlcoverage/*.*'
            }                    
         }        

      }
}
```

I have added the line *sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins ./docs/unit-tests/htmlcoverage* because I was facing a permissions error to the coverage file :

```
INTERNALERROR> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'coverage.xml'
```

I have also verified that coverage.xml is under root user and not the regular jenkins user (**What even causes this?**) :

[image: permissions]

What I have tried :

```
echo “jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL” >> /etc/sudoers
```

This results in the same error `sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper`

```
echo “jenkins ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL” >> /etc/sudoers
```

This also results in the same error `sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper`

In both cases I have done a restart of the jenkins service. The jenkins user is also already added to sudo group.

What exactly am I missing ?

Comment: The pipeline run as user `gold`, but `jenkins`, thus you should `echo “glod ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL” >> /etc/sudoers`

Comment: But the wired part is the `coverage.xml` is already exists before running`pytest` cmd, how is it created with root user.

Comment: hi @yong  Pipeline is started by the user account that installed the jenkins instance .. but by default pipeline runs as jenkins user .. I have just confirmed. That coverage.xml is from an earlier build which I did not delete. That build was using Docker agent not Agent any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this - the problem was with rules precedence inside `/etc/sudoers`.

By default *if there are multiple entries for a user inside of the `/etc/sudoers` file, sudo uses the last rule that applies*

The change to `jenkins` user was being overridden because of the rule's position in `/etc/sudoers` :

WRONG[image: WRONG]

It is wrong because jenkins user is already a member of sudo group, and thus the line `jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` will be overriden by the line

```
sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

CORRECT

[image: CORRECT]

Answer (score 1):

As the `docs` folder owned by root, you have to clean up it by root, you can add a temporary stage to clean it as following, once you ensure your pipeline won't use root, you can remove the temporary stage

```
stage('Clean Test Report') {
    steps {
        sh '''
            docker run -t \
                -u root \
                -v "$(pwd)":"$(pwd)" \
                -w "$(pwd) \
                --entrypoint='' \
                <what ever a docker image> \
                rm -rf docs
        '''
    }
}

stage('Unit Tests'){ 
   steps{
       withPythonEnv('/usr/bin/python3.8') {
         sh '''
            ls -al
            pip install -r requirements.txt
            pytest -v \
                --junitxml=docs/unit-tests/htmlcoverage/coverage.xml \
                --cov-report xml \
                --cov app.main
        '''
     }           
    }                    
}
```

To prevent pipeline run container as root, you can do as following

```
# run container by sh step
sh '''
  docker run \
    -u $(id -u):$(id -g) \
    -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd \
    ...
'''

# run container by docker global variable
container = docker.image(<image>).run(
    '-u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -t', 
    'cat'
)

docker.image(<image>).withRun(
   '-u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -t', 'cat') { container ->
   sh """
      docker exec -it ${container.id} -c \
        "pip install .. \
         pytest ..
        "
   """
}

docker.image(<image>).inside('-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd') {
# inside() run container as current host user by default

   sh '''
      pip install .. \
      pytest ...
   '''
}

# specify container as agent
# which runs container as current host user by default
agent {
   docker {
     args: '-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd'
   }   
}

agent {
   dockerfile {
     args: '-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd'
   }   
}
```

Comment: thanks @yong for the insights. I finally got what I was doing wrong